# Differing proofs with Hartshorne on morphism between affine varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification

> Let $F: X \to Y$ be a morphism between affine varieties $X$ and $Y$. Show that $F$ is continuous with respect to the Zariski topology.

I managed to prove this fact by taking a closed set $Z \in Y$ and noting that $Z$ must be of form $Z=V(g_1, \dots, g_r)$. Then considering the preimage $$\begin{align}F^{-1}(Z) &= \{x \in X \mid F(x) \in Z\} \\ &= \{x \in X \mid F(x) \in V(g_1, \dots,g_r)\}  \end{align}$$ and $x \in F^{-1}(Z) \iff F(x) \in V(g_1, \dots,g_r) \iff g_1(F(x))= \dots = g_r(F(x))=0 \iff x \in V(g_1(F), \dots ,g_r(F))$ implying that $F^{-1}(Z)=V(g_1(F), \dots ,g_r(F))$ and is thus closed making $F$ continuous.

*However*, I'm starting to question my proof as Hartshorne has the following proof that is quite different

He proves the statement

> A regular function is continuous, when $k$ is identified with $\Bbb A^1_k$ in its Zariski topology.

where I suppose that a regular function is a meant to be the same as a morphism between affine varieties as I'm calling them. He gives the following proof

> It is enough to show that $f^{-1}$ of a closed set is closed. A closed set of $\Bbb A^1_k$ is a finite set of points, so it is sufficient to show that $f^{-1}(a) = \{ P \in Y \mid f(P) = a\}$ is closed for any a $a \in k$. This can be checked locally: a subset $Z$ of a topological space $Y$ is closed if and only if $Y$ can be covered by open subsets $U$ such that $Z \cap U$ is closed in $U$ for each $U$. So let $U$ be an open set on which $f$ can be represented as $g/h$, with $g,h \in A$, and $h$ nowhere $0$ on $U$. Then $f^{-1}(a) \cap U = \{P \in U \mid g(P)/h(P) = a\}$. But $g(P)/h(P) = a$ if and only if $(g - ah)(P) = 0$. So $f^{-1}(a) \cap U = Z(g - ah) \cap U$ which is closed. Hence $f^{-1}(a)$ is closed in $Y$.

His proof has quite a few remarks which I don't understand, but I'm not sure are we proving the same thing here or is there something that I'm not thinking in my proof?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, in your proof, a regular function $F\colon X \to \mathbb{A}^{1}$ is
defined as the restriction of an ambient polynomial to $X$ (which allows you to
conclude that $g_i \circ F$ are still polynomials).

Hartshorne's definition of a regular function is a local one, namely, a function
is regular if it is *locally* a ratio of polynomials.

For a closed subvariety $X \subset \mathbb{A}^{n}$, the two definitions agree,
by Hilbert Nullstellensatz --- see Hartshorne's p. 17, Theorem 3.2. But
Hartshorne proves the continuity before the said theorem, so the argument is
slightly more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof looks correct to me. The two claims are not *technically* equivalent, but they functionally are. A morphism $f \colon X \to Y$ of affine varieties can be regarded as a morphism $f \colon X \to \mathbb{A}^n$ whose image lies in $Y$. Then if the composition of $f$ with the projections onto each factor $\mathbb{A}^1$ of $\mathbb{A}^n$ are continuous, $f$ is continuous as well. These are by definition regular functions, so Hartshorne's claim implies the more general one.